# Binding a list of objects to a list of checkboxes

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of objects, each with a few fields, like this:

```
function Person(id,name,age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var listOfPeople = [
    new Person(1, 'Fred', 25),
    new Person(2, 'Joe', 60),
    new Person(3, 'Sally', 43)
];

var viewModel = {
    this.people = ko.observableArray(listOfPeople);
    this.selectedPeople = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

I would like to build a list of checkboxes, one for each person, something along these lines:

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id, checked: ?">
        <span data-bind="name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My confusion is that in the checkbox `data-bind` attribute, I would like to refer to both the object being selected (that is, the `person` or the person's `id`), as well as to the list of all selected people. How do I refer to that in the scope of the `foreach` binding?

I guess a corollary is: how do I refer to the object being bound? Here "`this`" seemed to be bound to the window, not to the object.

The example of the "[`checked` binding on the knockoutjs site](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)" deals with primitives and uses a named template. I am confused about how to do this with objects and with anonymous templates.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can do something like:

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: $parent.selectedPeople">
    </li>
</ul>
```

With this kind of ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray(listOfPeople),
    selectedPeople: ko.observableArray()
};
```

The `value` attribute controls what the `checked` binding adds/removes from an array when it is bound against an array.  You could also write a dependentObservable that populates the array with the actual objects, if necessary.

**Live Example:**

```js
function Person(id,name,age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var listOfPeople = [
    new Person(1, 'Fred', 25),
    new Person(2, 'Joe', 60),
    new Person(3, 'Sally', 43)
];

var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray(listOfPeople),
    selectedPeople: ko.observableArray([1])
};

    
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: $parent.selectedPeople"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<hr/>

<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I recommend using `$parent.selectedPeople` because it will actually go up one level. `$root` will go all the way to the root view model, and if you have nested view-models, then `$parent` is guaranteed.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer, is there something about using `attr: {value: xx }` rather than just using the value binding? I was having issues getting the checked binding to work properly because all values were being checked in unison. Thanks for all your documented support!

Comment: The `value` binding sets up a two-way binding meaning that it adds event handlers (which `checked` already does). So, conflicts can happen there.  The `attr` binding will just make sure that the attribute (`value` in this case) is updated as the view model data changes.

Comment: @ShaunMcCarthy: That's no longer true with the `checkedValue` binding. (It *was* true when you made that comment re Ryan's original answer using the old `attr: { value: id }` binding instead.)