# knockout.js checkboxes used to control enabled/disabled state of input fields

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

I am trying to bind a checkbox to each line in a list of objects, in a very similar fashion to a question asked/answered here: [Binding a list of objects to a list of checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613602/binding-a-list-of-objects-to-a-list-of-checkboxes)

Essentially, as follows:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: phones">
  <li>
    <input type='text' data-bind="attr: {value:phone}, disable: $root.selectedPhones"/>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {value:id}, checked: $root.selectedPhones" />
  </li>
</ul>

<hr/> selected phones:
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedPhones)"></div>
<hr/> phones:
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.phones)"></div>
```

with js as follows:

```
function Phone(id,phone) {
  this.id = id;
  this.phone = phone;
}

var phones_list = [
  new Phone(1, '11111'),
  new Phone(2, '22222'),
  new Phone(3, '33333')
];

var viewModel = {
  phones: ko.observableArray(phones_list),
  selectedPhones: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The idea being that in the initial state, all of the input boxes are disabled and that clicking a checkbox will enable the input box in that row.

The data is coming from a fairly deeply nested object from the server-side so I'd like to avoid 'padding' the data with an additional boolean ie *avoiding* `new Phone(1,'xx', false)`
(a) because it's probably unnecessary (b) because the structure is almost certainly going to change...

Can the `selectedPhones` observable be used by the enable/disable functionality to control the status of fields in that 'row'?

Hope someone can help....

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RobertSudwarts/oxjyxa5y/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small helper function which checks that a given `id` appers in the `selectedPhones`:

```
var viewModel = {
    phones: ko.observableArray(phones_list),
    selectedPhones: ko.observableArray(),
    enableEdit: function(id) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.selectedPhones(), 
           function(p) { return p == id })
    }
};
```

Then you can use this helper function in your `enable` binding:

```
<input type='text' data-bind="attr: {value:phone}, disable: $root.enableEdit(id)"/>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwfjzkpj/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pwkad/oxjyxa5y/3/ - Should also remove attr: value and replace with value binding

Comment: Thank you both (and for the additional comment): quite correct, the attr: value isn't required.